# Gremlin.net throwing exception when using tree

Tags: tinkerpop, gremlinnet

When using the following query in Gremlin.net, I get the exception: `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key 'DataType{ TypeCode = 43 }' was not present in the dictionary.'`

```
var result = g
  .V()
  .Repeat(OutE("composed-of").InV().SimplePath())
  .Tree<object>()
  .Promise<dynamic>(t => t.ToList());
```

Server is running from docker:

```
- services
    gramling_server:
      image: tinkerpop/gremlin-server
      restart: always
      platform: linux/x86_64
      ports:
        - "8182:8182"
      volumes:
        - tinkerpop_data_container:/data
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed the **messageSerializer** on the **GremlinClient** class to **GraphSON3MessageSerializer** and get the following error.
`Deserializer for "g:Tree" not found`.
My guess is "TypeCode 43" is this g:Tree

Comment: I need to check specifically regarding the .Net client, but in general, the non-Java based clients do not support `tree` and `subgraph` as there is no native data structure for them to deserialize into. The Python client is a bit of a weird exception but it just returns the tree as raw GraphSON. If I learn anything more I will update this comment, but in general the non Java clients do not support tree. This is something the TinkerPop community would like to improve in the future.

Comment: Hi @Kelvin Lawrence. Thanks for your reply. Digging through the library I can see you are correct. There doesn't seem to be a deserilaiser for the tree. Are there any other options? Perhaps a way to get the raw JSON? I would prefer to keep the result in a hierarchy rather than getting it as a flat list if I can

Comment: You can't just get raw JSON back but you could write your own deserializer for `"g:Tree"` and that can then simply return the JSON / deserialize it into a Dictionary or whatever. The interface you need to implement for this with GraphSON is: [IGraphSONDeserializer](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-dotnet/src/Gremlin.Net/Structure/IO/GraphSON/IGraphSONDeserializer.cs)